# Can Canadians enter Belarus with no visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, canadian-citizens, visa-free-entry, belarus

I think the following question has not been answered yet, at least not in light of the new regulations.

> **Question:** a Canadian citizen can enter Belarus ["visa-free"](http://www.belarus.by/en/press-center/press-release/five-day-visa-free-regime-to-enter-into-force-in-belarus-on-12-february-2017_i_51265.html). What's the  exact meaning of this?
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Belarus) says "visa free for five days".
>
> But the [consulate of Belarus in Canada](http://canada.mfa.gov.by/en/consular_issues/) seems to not mention this and does mention support papers sent in advance.
>
> So, can a Canadian citizen just land at Minsk without any previous paperwork, and be awarded a 5-day visa? Is there a cost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The embassy site is confusing and the relevant info (even in English) is for some reason easier to locate through the Russian-language version. [Relevant page in English](http://canada.mfa.gov.by/en/consular_issues/visas/ac39703729cf7873.html).

Summary: you can visit without a visa or advance application if you fly to the Minsk airport, unless you are flying from Russia. You need medical insurance and a small amount of cash. If you use this option, you also have to leave from the Minsk airport - you cannot leave over a land border.

Answer (score 1):

> So, can a Canadian citizen just land at Minsk without any previous paperwork, and be awarded a 5-day visa?

There is no such thing as a 5-day visa. You enter visa-free, with no prior paperwork.

> a Canadian citizen can enter Belarus "visa-free". What's the exact meaning of this?

It means you enter without a visa - in other words, present your passport and get stamped in, just like when travelling to the US.

You cannot transit Russia on the way to/from Belarus, and have to both enter **and** exit through Minsk airport. If you overstay due to illness (for example) you need to supply evidence and obtain and exit visa, which you can then use to exit anywhere

> Is there a cost?

No

> But the consulate of Belarus in Canada seems to not mention this and does mention support papers sent in advance.

That is if you want to get a visa on arrival, which you no longer need if staying for max 5 days.